# json return to the format

Tags: iphone, ios, json

Api Address：
http://suggest.taobao.com/sug?area=etao&code=utf-8&callback=KISSY.Suggest.callback&q=iphone

return：

```
KISSY.Suggest.callback({"result": [["iphone4s", "9809"], ["iphone5", "13312"], ["iphone4 手机", "69494400"], ["iphone5 港行", "14267"], ["iphone5三网", "2271160"], ["iphone4手机壳", "6199679"], ["iphone 5手机壳", "2527284"], ["iphone 5 保护壳", "5727586"], ["iphone 4贴膜", "147271"], ["iphone5壳", "2628540"]]})


NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://suggest.taobao.com/sug?area=etao&code=utf-8&callback=KISSY.Suggest.callback&q=iphone"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSHTTPURLResponse* urlResponse = nil;

NSError * error = nil;

NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error];

NSData *date = [NSData alloc]init

SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];


// NSMutableArray *array=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];
    NSMutableArray *array = [jsonParser objectWithData:responseData];

    NSLog(@"%@",array);
```

this array is null.  i dont know the reason.

Comment: I'm afraid it has something to do with your encoding and those Japanese? Characters.

Comment: nothing to worry about Japanese, it can be parsed, refer my answer below. just follow the instructions and you will be through.

Comment: thank you ，but string is chinese

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as i refer you request URL ,it has callback in it, if you keep it, it will not return you json as response, so remove "&callback=KISSY.Suggest.callback" from your URL

```
// Make sure you have include SBJSON files in your Project, as well you have imported header in your View Controller
#import "JSON.h"

// your request URL
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://suggest.taobao.com/sug?area=etao&code=utf-8&q=iphone"];

// URL Request
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSHTTPURLResponse* urlResponse = nil;

NSError * error = nil;

// initiate Request to get Data
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error];

// Encode your Response
NSString *content = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[responseData bytes] length:[responseData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

// Now read a Dictionary from it using SBJSON Parser
NSDictionary *responseDict = [content JSONValue];

NSLog(@"Response [%@]",responseDict);
```

Comment: it returns me response , let me edit your code and my answer as well, just wait for a moment

Comment: @paul now paste this code and enjoy...! and let me know your insight.

Comment: thank you  very much, i try it ps:sorry ,my english is bad T_T

Comment: YES  good，Thank you very much，i try it,Test is passed, I would like to learn a code。tank you

Comment: sure read, my comments carefully you will understand it, what is in code., and feel free to ask your query on my email id, thats on my profile page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the SBJsonParser, but the format of the returned string looks like JSONP, not JSON. I would imagine simply cleaning out the wrapper call would get you what you are after.

Also, note that the 'root' of your response is a dictionary, not an array.

```
{"result": [[...
```

means that the code might should look like this:

```
NSDictionary *response = //... decode
NSArray *results = [response objectForKey:@"result"];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**

You just need to use http://suggest.taobao.com/sug?area=etao&code=utf-8&q=iphone instead of http://suggest.taobao.com/sug?area=etao&code=utf-8&callback=KISSY.Suggest.callback&q=iphone you own code will work..

Comment: thank you，yes，I think so, but I do not know how to get rid of the previous string.  ps：my english is bad  sorry

Comment: hi thank you very much,i try it,Direct crash.  i thinkNSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://suggest.taobao.com/sug?area=etao&code=utf-8&callback=KISSY.Suggest.callback&q=设计"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];  the request  back return is null.

Comment: The code is not tested, you need to check it.. By the way you don't need my code above just use this url http://suggest.taobao.com/sug?area=etao&code=utf-8&q=iphone, your own code will work..

Comment: thank you very much ,To solve the above problem is he is, thank you